# Two questions: Size and Files

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much space does Ubuntu 12.04 take up after it's already installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169727/how-much-space-does-ubuntu-12-04-take-up-after-its-already-installed)

My questions and concerns are that my windows vista pc is old and so slow, i have been trying to boost its performance but nothing happens, so i decided that i want to switch to ubuntu because the software on vista is not good either and i want to know how much space ubuntu takes up on the pc and i have been playing games on steam in vista and wanted to know if i would have to install it on ubuntu if i were to install it.

Comment: To answer your second question: a native Steam client is not yet available for Ubuntu, however, Valve has plans to release one in the future. Right now, you can install the Steam client via PlayOnLinux: see also this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-run-steam

Answer (score 0):

Ok so ubuntu only uses 8gb +/- hard drive space that's way better then windows 20gb just to install.

steam is coming to linux very soon you can still use steam using wine and play on linux only thing most gams do not work yet.

Valve: “Windows 8 a Catastrophe for Everyone”
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/valve-windows-8-a-catastrophe

Valve Confirm ‘Steam’, ‘Left 4 Dead 2′ Coming to Ubuntu
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/valve-confirm-steam-left-4-dead-2-coming-to-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, the Ubuntu linux distribution takes up small disk space. In fact, when you are installing it, it is happy with as much as 4.4 GB of free disk space. Now, you wouldn't want it to run with that little space, due to future upgrades and stuff, however, it could run just fine with any disk size > 10GB.

For your second question, Steam doesn't run natively on Ubuntu. As a matter of fact it doesn't run natively on any Linux distribution. However, you have to know that Valve, it's developer, is making an attempt to port Steam and the games on the platform to linux, and more specifically Ubuntu. More info on the matter here: [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=valve_linux_dampfnudeln&num=1) and [Valve linux blog](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/).

You could also try to run Steam and some games via WINE. However doing so might result in unacceptable game performance or even sometimes to unstable games. However if you are so keen on doing it, here is an official guide from the [VALVe wiki.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux)

Comment: I was also wondering if all of my files would carry over to ubuntu

Comment: Perhaps, if you installed Ubuntu on a dual boot configuration, you might be able to access your files via the hard disk. However, if you follow a clean install, and format your hard disk, it will be pretty much wiped from all its contents, so in any case, before you actually do anything, it is highly advised to back up the files that are of high importance to you.