# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 while planning to install another OS alongside in the future

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I'd like to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a 512GB HDD. I'll definitely not need the whole space for one OS, and I plan to install other distros alongside Ubuntu  for short term projects, removing them afterwards.

I wonder what is the best option to achieve this.

> 1. Use 256 GB for Ubuntu and leave 256 GB of unallocated space as a placeholder for future OS installs.
> 2. Install Ubuntu on whole disk capacity using LVM, and resize it in future to install another OS.

I think that option 2 is much better, but I could not find any tutorials that presents on how to resize LVM and install another OS in the space made available, so I'm not quite sure if this procedure is safe for my main OS, nor do I understand how difficult it would be.

Do you recommend either of these solutions? Is there another way?

Comment: Option 1 is definitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-18-04-faq/) does not need anywhere near 256 GB. The files created by a full Ubuntu install (before you add any more packages) is [5 GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169727/how-much-space-does-ubuntu-take-up-after-its-already-installed), and the swap file (for [swap partitions are passé](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048785/can-swap-files-be-located-in-separate-partitions-such-as-an-old-swap-partition)) should be no more than your RAM size to start.

If you started with less (like, oh, say, 30 GB or 100 GB), you can always resize the default [ext4 partitions](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/ext4-filesystem) of what you listed as your first option up or down if you need more space, with a [LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0), such as you will use to [install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).